# How to plot three enclosed surfaces based on data (x,y,z)?

Tags: matlab, geometry, mesh

30 points are given in R^3. How can we approximate given points (x,y,z) with **three continuous closed** surfaces? Note that there are **three** different "levels" or "surfaces" like

- (1) yolk of an egg;
- (2) white of an egg;
- (3) shell.

---

The surfaces are enclosed in each other, they **do not intersect**.
By running the code below you will see framework of 3D figures of red, black and blue color. These three frameworks should be approximated my three **surfaces**. How can we do it? Please help! Thank you in advance for any attempt!

### Source data:

```
clear all
clc
%level 1, the smallest, inside all; "north" and "south" points are in the process 
x_527=[-2.5 -2.625 -2.6]
y_527=[0.0135 0.0145 0.0145]
z_527=[6.8168 6.8168 6.8168]
%level 2, in the middle, 3D, "north" and "south" points are PRESENT
x_615=[-2.32 -2.5 -2.54 -2.7 -2.9 -2.51 -2.67 -2.6125 -2.2 -2.5 -2.9 ]
y_615=[0.0122 0.014 0.0145 0.016 0.02 0.0145 0.0145 0.014 0.0115 0.0145 0.02 ]
z_615=[6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.7 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 7 6.8168 ]
%level 3, the biggest; flat, "north" and "south" points are in the process 
x_756=[-1.5  -2.4  -2.7 -2.756 -3.407 -3.652 -2.683 -1.5 -2.5 -3.652 -2.5 -1.5]
y_756=[0.006 0.0115  0.014 0.0145 0.02 0.022 0.02 0.006 0.0145 0.022 0.0145 0.006]
z_756=[6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 6.8168 8.7 6.8168 5.15 6.8168]
plot3(x_527,y_527,z_527,'rx',x_527,y_527,z_527,'red',x_615,y_615,z_615,'blacks',x_615,y_615,z_615,'black',x_756,y_756,z_756,'bo',x_756,y_756,z_756,'blue','MarkerSize',7,'LineWidth',2);
%drawing three levels one inside another using source (x,y,z) data
grid on;
title('Error function F(alpha)','FontSize',15,'fontname','times')
    xlabel('Parameter alpha_{0}','FontSize',14,'fontname','times')
    ylabel('Parameter alpha_{1}','FontSize',14,'fontname','times')
    zlabel('Parameter alpha_{2}','FontSize',14,'fontname','times')
    hleg1 = legend('Errors q-ty: 5.27%','','Errors q-ty: 6.15%','','Errors q-ty: 7.56%','');
```

This will generate this plot:

[image: original plot]

Comment: What programming language is this in?  My instinct says MATLAB

Comment: @rayryeng This is indeed valid MATLAB syntax, but nowhere near readable...

Comment: @AlexR - Agreed, but still voting to close.  All this is is a bunch of 3D points.  It could be anything really.

Comment: @rayryeng Jup. I have tried to make it at least readable and removed the completely out-of-scope tag [tag:surf]... Such a question wouldn't even get an answer at Math.SE I guess due to its bad formulation...

Comment: As it turns out, these points do not show any clear relation and do not define a plausible surface; they just form an unstructured point could. You can compute its convex hull (a polyhedron), but I doubt this is what you are looking for. You should tell us more.

Comment: Are you looking for three surfaces or just one surface which approximates these points? Or a fit? Or just a mesh?

Comment: 1. Yes, Matlab. 2. Yes, could be formulated better. 3. Absolutely true: there is unstructured point cloud. But if we examine three different meanings of "z" coordinate, then there are three structured "clouds". The smallest, the middle and the biggest, outside them. I have a pic. How can I add it?

Comment: @EJG89: **Three** **continuous** surfaces are needed. The smallest "cloud" inside middle, the middle inside the biggest. Fit/mesh - don't mind. It should just be visible that there are "clouds" one inside another. Like in an egg.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Given data are not full. Data (x,y,z) can be random. The question is how to draw a "chicken egg" with three levels: (1) yellow yolk, (2) white of an egg and (3) shell. These three surfaces should be continuous and closed. (2) and (3) should be transparent, so (1) could be visible.

Comment: @Schorsch link to a figure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByOTdzO3fjb4MnBNNDFyZ2NHRzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: haha I think I finally get it (can't access your figure though). I should get a badge for deciphering your question first if I'm right ;)

Comment: How is the new data, which has the same `z`-coordinate for all but two points, related to the initial data in the question?

Comment: @Schorsch the new data is updated. Yes, the z-coordinates are the same for all but two points (Let's call them "South Pole" and "North Pole"). It should be better to add  "South Pole" and "North Pole" to the outer and inner level. I've not done it yet. But you can imagine that they exist. So, how to approximate at least middle level with a surface?

Comment: @EJG89 With great pleasure. How can I add bonus for your help and understanding?

Answer (score 2):

Still not exactly sure what you want but I assume you want to plot the convexhull (2D) of each level:

```
clear all
clc

x = [-2.5   -2.625  -2.6    -2.32   -2.5    -2.54   -2.7    -2.9    -2.51   -2.67   -2.6125 -2.2    -2.5    -2.9    -1.5    -2.4    -2.7    -2.756  -3.407  -3.652  -2.683  -1.5];
y = [0.0135 0.0145  0.0145  0.0122  0.014   0.0145  0.016   0.02    0.0145  0.0145  0.014   0.0115  0.0145  0.02    0.006   0.0115  0.014   0.0145  0.02    0.022   0.02    0.006];
z = [5.27   5.27    5.27    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    6.15    7.56    7.56    7.56    7.56    7.56    7.56    7.56    7.56];

% Surface level 1
x1=x(1:3);
y1=y(1:3);
z1=z(1:3);
% Surface level 2
x2=x(4:14);
y2=y(4:14);
z2=z(4:14);
% Surface level 3
x3=x(15:22);
y3=y(15:22);
z3=z(15:22);

% Determine convexhull indices
K1 = convhull(x1,y1);
K2 = convhull(x2,y2);
K3 = convhull(x3,y3);

% Plot convex hulls
figure()
hold on

fill3(x1(K1),y1(K1),z1(K1),[1 0 0])

fill3(x2(K2),y2(K2),z2(K2),[0 1 0])

fill3(x3(K3),y3(K3),z3(K3),[0 0 1])
```

After plotting swivel the figure view a bit around to see if this is what you want.

Good luck!

Comment: We need to plot the convexhull (3D) [not 2 D] of each level.

Comment: This is NOT 3D data. This is three sets of 2D data. You need to compute 3 2D convex hulls and draw them on top of each other.

Comment: +1 for your Yves.  You managed to ascertain the real question underneath all of this obfuscation.  @user3872698... why don't you just **edit** your post with this code?  Reading code in comments is just plain stupid and the formatting is unacceptable.